# Using :not and bootstrap to override styles

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my `style.css` I define my link color as:

```
a {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

However it is overriding the default colors for the links in bootstrap alerts which I also use (and bootstrap in general) as a scaffolding.

I read that one can use `:not` to override certain things.

I'm trying to avoid changing or using `!important` in bootstrap as I am grabbing it from a cdn.

So I tried this:

```
a:not(.alert > a) {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover:not(.alert > a) {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success" id="autoclose-success">
Some message here.<a href="#" class="close dismiss-messages dismiss-messages-processed"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></a>
</div>
```

But it is not working. Am I using it wrong? What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: This is not valid: `a:not(.alert > a) {` - you'll need to find another selector.  You cannot access "parent" elements like you are attempting to with `.alert`....

Comment: You'll have to reproduce your issue more exactly as `a` and `a:hover` should not affect the alert styles since their selector `.alert-success` is more specific. [JSFiddle demonstrating proper styling](https://jsfiddle.net/5vut2kf0/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:not()` (or any CSS selectors at this time) cannot traverse up the DOM to parent selectors.

So, unfortunately, you'd need to do something like so in your override styles:

```
.alert a {
    /* override styles here for any a element IN .alert */
}
```

Or, alternatively:

```
:not(.alert) a {
    /* override styles for anything EXCEPT alert > a */
}
```

So long as your override styles are loaded *after* bootstrap is loaded, there is no need for `!important`

Answer (score 1):

That's the wrong usage for [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not),

> The negation CSS pseudo-class, `:not(X)`, is a functional notation
>   taking a simple selector X as an argument. It matches an element that
>   is not represented by the argument. X must not contain another
>   negation selector.

To override it, you need to be more specific in your rule, something like this:

```css
.parent .alert-dismissible .close {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.parent .alert-dismissible .close:hover {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="parent">

  <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success" id="autoclose-success">
    Some message here.<a href="#" class="close dismiss-messages dismiss-messages-processed"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```